# Redirecting to the correct page after submitting a form in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have the same

```
@Html.ActionLink("SUSPEND", "Suspend", "Serials", new { id = s.serial, orderId = s.Order.orderID }, null)
```

on two different pages.

Let's say I can click on it from this page:

```
http://localhost:55058/Customers/Details/4106
```

and from this page:

```
http://localhost:55058/Orders/Details/102091
```

The link takes me to a form associated to two standard Controller actions, GET:

```
public ActionResult Suspend(string id, string orderId)
{
   Serial serial = context.Serials.Single(x => x.serialID == id);

   ViewBag.orderId = orderId;

   return View(serial);
}
```

and POST:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Suspend(Serial serial, string orderId)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
         serial.suspended = true;
         serial.suspensionDate = DateTime.Now;
         context.Entry(serial).State = EntityState.Modified;
         context.SaveChanges();

         ViewBag.orderId = orderId;

         return View(context.Serials.Single(x => x.serialID == serial.serialID));
    }
}
```

How do I `Redirect()` to the page *where I first clicked the link*, once I submitted the form? *Possibly, in an elegant way...*

Thanks.

Comment: Doesn't it get me back to the GET page?

Comment: yes..then what else do you want..???

Comment: Note that you'll have to get the url referrer in the get action, then somehow pass it to your post for redirection.  url referrer in your post will refer to your intermediate get, not the original one.

Comment: @Erik: Interesting, what approach do you suggest?

Comment: @Alberto - Using TempData for a Post/Redirect/Get pattern should work

Comment: @Erik: Please post an answer so I can mark it.